# Is it possible to load the kendo react form using default values on page load

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I'm working on kendo react UI and have I have to implement edit data UI page. For edit data, the given design is the design of a form so I added the kendo react form component to the UI but I can't place any value to the form UI while loading page. Fetch the data from the API and not possible to add to the form fields. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There are different ways to achieve this, but the general idea is the same. Render component with form (make form to take some default/empty data from state), request data, once recieved, update the state), state will be changed and the component rerender will be triggered feeding in new values to the form